# Error: identifier "_S_IFDIR" is undefined

Tags: c, windows, directory

I've just opened one of my old projects in visual studio (windows) adding directory test and found the compilation error.
I just copied the function from my other working project and added the same headers.
If you click F12 stats.h is opened and you get the identifier but somehow compiler does not see it?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void my_function()
{
...
    struct _stat buf;        
    _wstat(dir, &buf);
    if ((buf.st_mode & _S_IFDIR) > 0) { // here _S_IFDIR undefined
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag with the relevant system. For Unix, there is no underscore at the start of `stat` and `S_IFDIR` and there is no `_wstat`.

Comment: Yes, stat.h. I'm using visual studio in windows. S_IFDIR is also declared in stat.h as _S_IFDIR

Answer (score 1):

As the POSIX symbol is `S_ISDIR` and your system seems to mostly follow POSIX but adding a leading underscore, perhaps `_S_IFDIR` should be replaced by `_S_ISDIR` (ie. replace **F** by **S**) ?

Comment: thanks, that does not work, _S_ISDIR can not be found with F12 either

Answer (score 1):

You can try by adding the following define:

```
#if defined __WIN32__ || defined _WIN32 || defined _Windows
      #if !defined S_ISDIR
            #define S_ISDIR(m) (((m) & _S_IFDIR) == _S_IFDIR)
      #endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `_S_IFDIR` is between some `#if` check and that is not getting true.

```
//sys/stat.h
#ifdef SOMETHING  // <--- this needs to be true to activate below code
//...
#define _S_IFDIR 0
//...
#endif
```

Comment: @Chesnokov, yes so I have given the same example if you see my answer.  Have mentioned `sys/stat.h` in the comment; which means the file name. Check your file and see if the macro is defined somewhere in between `#if-#endif`

Comment: I see, there are neither macros nor defines named _S_IFDIR in my project. _S_IFDIR is active in stat.h